# Movie with a guy in a commercial who turns people into weird creatures

Tags: story-identification, movie

So basically, this guy turns people into weird creatures for his commercial, and I think some people save them by defeating him. If anyone can help me figure out what this is, please do.

I don't know how to explain it better, so I'm sorry if this isn't much to work off of. I don't remember anything about it. It might not even be a movie.

Comment: Perhaps this is "Spy Kids", which features a character who populates his television kids' show with transformed humans?

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! By "it might not even be a movie," did you mean that it might be a TV show or movie? Also, to increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our [guide on asking identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957).

Comment: @StanleyWebb tysm that is it

Comment: @helppls: I've posted a stub answer. Feel free to crib any or all of that for your answer. Ditto for Stanley. If you post it, I'll delete mine. Also, helppls, you can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

The querent confirmed Stanley Webb's guess that it might be [the first *Spy Kids* film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spy_Kids_(film)).

> Gregorio and Ingrid Cortez are spies with two children, Carmen and Juni, whom they shield from their lives to protect them from inherent danger. They work for the Organization of Super Spies (OSS) doing office consultant work, but are suddenly called back to active field work to find missing agents. Gregorio suspects children's television host Fegan Floop has kidnapped them, mutating them into his "Fooglies" – creatures on his show. The children are left in the care of their uncle, Felix Gumm.

### Trailer